# removing link characters from name after webscraping

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I am trying to remove characters such as [e] or [f] etc., which are attached to end of names when we scrape data from websites but facing problems with it.
I am using code

`url= "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:COVID-19_pandemic_data#covid19-container"
response= requests.get(url)
response`

`inf= response.content
scraping = BeautifulSoup(inf, "lxml") 
scraping
element = scraping.find('table')
df = pd.read_html(str(element))[0]
df`

`df['countries'] = df['countries'].str.strip('[(.[*]\)]')`

But the output received from the above code is not accurate as I am getting
United States[e , Russia[f, United Kingdom[g, Spain[h , Germany[I    etc.
Can anyone help me how to fix this issue?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
df['Country'] = df['Country'].str.replace('\[\w\]', "")
```

This will be able to remove the square bracket and anything inside it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply..It did remove most of them but not all. I still have some countries which has the links

Comment: can you send me a example for which it didn't work.